# Failed to notify project evaluation listener. Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 142

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube

I have to analyze my project with sonarqube plugin for gradle. I set the plugin dependencies. But everytime i start the command "gradlew sonarqube" it shows me this error. I have 5.1.1 gradle versione and jdk 1.8.0_211.

I've already tried to check the option "Use embedded JDK", i've already tried to uncheck the option "Instant Run" on Android Studio. I have no clues.

This is the error:
           * What went wrong:
          A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Uninitialized object exists on backward branch 142
>                Exception Details:
>                Location:
>                com/android/build/gradle/internal/pipeline/VariantInfoImpl. 
>                (Lcom/android/build/gradle/internal/scope/
>                VariantScope;)V @200: goto
>                Reason:
>                    Error exists in the bytecode
>                    Bytecode:
>                    0x0000000: 2b12 3cb8 0034 2a2b b900 4201 0059 1244
>                    0x0000010: b800 47b6 004d b900 5201 002b b900 5401
>                    0x0000020: 0059 1256 b800 472b b900 4201 0059 1244
>                    0x0000030: b800 47b6 005a c000 5c59 125e b800 47b9
>                    0x0000040: 0061 0100 5912 63b8 0047 2bb9 0042 0100
>                    0x0000050: 5912 44b8 0047 b600 6759 1269 b800 47c0
>                    0x0000060: 006b 4d3a 0e3a 0d36 0c3a 0b03 3e2c 3a04
>                    0x0000070: bb00 6d59 2c10 0ab8 0073 b700 76c0 0078
>                    0x0000080: 3a05 0336 0619 04b9 007c 0100 3a07 1907
>                    0x0000090: b900 8101 0099 0036 1907 b900 8501 003a
>                    0x00000a0: 0819 0519 08c0 0087 3a09 3a0f 0336 0a19
>                    0x00000b0: 0959 1289 b800 47b9 008a 0100 3a10 190f
>                    0x00000c0: 1910 b900 8e02 0057 a7ff c619 05c0 0090
>                    0x00000d0: 3a0f 190b 150c 190d 190e 190f c000 6bb8
>                    0x00000e0: 0096 2bb9 0042 0100 5912 44b8 0047 b600
>                    0x00000f0: 5ac0 005c 5912 5eb8 0047 b900 9801 00b7
>                   0x0000100: 009a b1
>   And this is my code:

1.build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  dataBinding {
    enabled = true;
  }

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "uniba.di.itps.ciceroneapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube' // added for sonar qube

sonarqube {
properties {
    property "sonar.projectName", "Cicerone"
    property "sonar.projectKey", "Cicerone"
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
    property "sonar.language", "java"
    property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
    property "sonar.java.sources", "src/main/java"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
    property "sonar.login", "admin"
    property "sonar.password", "admin"
}
}
dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
   implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
   implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places- 
   compat:1.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.2'
   implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
   }



   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

2.build.gradle(project):

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle- 
    plugin:2.6.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'   
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
    }
  allprojects {
     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
     }
 }
  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

3.gradle.wrapper.properties

```
  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  distributionPath=wrapper/dists
  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1- 
  all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify build.gradle for dependency and repo details as mentioned in this link.

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube

And get more details on error using command.

```
gradlew sonarqube --info --stacktrace
```

Comment: This really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem. It seems Android Studio and Gradle use different JDK locations.

go to:

[Event log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk5h7.png)

And click on this option: "Set Android Studio to use the same JDK as Gradle and sync project."

You can manually set the exact JDK locations for Android Studio as Gradle.

You can also do this:
In Android Studio, go to the Help > Find Action... > search "JDK location". And set "JDK Location different to JAVA_HOME Popup state to "Balloon. This option helps you to see the proper balloon in this case.